# .htaccess redirect except one specific request

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have an .htaccess file see below

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

#Every www request to non-www
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]

#every http request in amdinistrator folder redirect to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/administrator
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

#every https request except ftp and one specific request redirect to http
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ftp
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/preview/index.php?request_type=preview_engime
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

#redirect which request contains PUBLIC_AJAX_ENGIME
RewriteRule ^(.*)PUBLIC_AJAX_ENGIME(.*)$ index.php?request_type=ajax_engime [L]

#files and directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

I do not want redirection in this case:

https://somewebsite.domain/preview/index.php?request_type=preview_engime

but the system redirects here

http://somewebsite.domain/index.php?request_type=preview_engime

and I do not understand why.

Thank you! 
FF

Answer (score 0):

This is because your url contains a querystring. You cant match against QueryString using REQUEST_URI variable. You need to match against THE_REQUEST variable. Replace your RewriteCond with this :

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/index\.php\?request_type=preview_engime [NC]
```

Comment: It's almost good ... now the request was redirected here:

http://    somewebsite.domain/preview/index.php?request_type=preview_engime

But I need https in this case.